# Как удалять/отменять настройки limits.conf с помощью ansible pam_limits?

Tags: linux, ansible, limits

Настраиваю `/etc/security/limits.conf` с помощью модуля Ansible [pam_limits](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pam_limits_module.html#pam-limits).

Что получается:

- Установить настройки для определённого домена и типа (в конец файла добавляется строка)
- Поменять значения (строка успешно переписывается на новую)

Что не могу понять: а как полностью удалить настройку? То есть я больше не хочу сохранять дампы ядра на данном хосте. Как использовать *pam_limits* или как добиться этого иным путём?

Пока что я придумал вот такое решение, но оно мне кажется костылём. Поскольку я не эксперт в linux, я также не уверен, что явная установка лимита в 0 эквивалентна отсутствию какой-либо настройки.

**roles/myrole/tasks/main.yaml**

```
...
- name: enable core dumps for myservice
  pam_limits: domain='serviceuser' limit_type='-' limit_item=core value=unlimited
  when: myrole_save_core_dumps

- name: disable core dumps for myservice
  pam_limits: domain='serviceuser' limit_type='-' limit_item=core value=0
  when: not myrole_save_core_dumps
...
```

**group_vars/myhosts.yaml:**

```
myrole_save_core_dumps: true
```

**myservice.yaml**

```
hosts: myhosts
become: yes
roles: 
  - myrole
```

Comment: заглянул в [исходник](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/blob/devel/system/pam_limits.py). там, вроде бы, нет проверки синтаксиса переменной `domain`. попробуйте добавить решётку в начало строки, присваиваемой этой переменной.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: попробую, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

предполагаемые варианты:

1. насколько я вижу, в [исходных текстах](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/blob/devel/system/pam_limits.py), вроде бы, нет проверки синтаксиса переменной `domain`. попробуйте добавить решётку в начало строки, присваиваемой этой переменной. строка после исправления окажется закомментированной.
2. для (вероятно) каждого процесса в псевдо-файловой системе `/proc` создаётся псевдо-файл `/proc/номер.процесса/limits`:

   ```
   $ cat /proc/$$/limits 
   Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
   Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
   Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
   Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
   Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
   Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
   Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
   Max processes             15548                15548                processes 
   Max open files            65536                65536                files     
   Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
   Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
   Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
   Max pending signals       15548                15548                signals   
   Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
   Max nice priority         0                    0                    
   Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
   Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
   ```

   умолчальные, указанные в коде программы *linux* значения, можно увидеть (и использовать), например, в информации о процессе с pid, равным единице. это первый и единственный процесс, запускаемый непосредственно программой *linux* (обычно он загружается из файла `/sbin/init`):

   ```
   $ cat /proc/1/limits
   ```
3. можно создавать/удалять не строки в `/etc/security/limits.conf`, а файлы в каталоге `/etc/security/limits.d`. согласно `man limits.conf`, они должны заканчиваться суффиксом `.conf`.